# Background App Fetch and App Snapshotting

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background-fetch

I am developing an app where I use iOS's "background app fetch" to keep the data of my app up to date.  This is working fine except the "snapshot"  of the app is not updated with this fetch.

When I say "snapshot" I mean the image that iOS takes when it goes into the background.  This is the image that is displayed for the second before your app loads.  At the moment this means users (particularly those on older phones)  may see old information for a second or so then have it replaced with new information.

Does anybody know more about when the app takes the snapshot and if this can be forced (for example when I fetch new data in the background).

Alternatively can anybody think of a way I can achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentations on [Managing the State Restoration Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW64). It's not possible to update the snapshot once you loaded new data from the background. What you can do is to just tell the `UIApplication` to not show the snapshot but the default launch image using `-ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch`.

In my opinion however, this shouldn't be necessary. I can image that Apple will improve this with iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

How about resetting your app to a "neutral" state when it is about to enter the background? Displaying an empty table, for example.

You won't have the latest data, but you won't have wrong data either.